# Clean up database connections at request completion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm dabbling in MVC3, and I'm putting together a site that connects to SQL Server (no big surprise there, I'm sure). I'm using a base class called SqlRepository that will be extended by various other repository classes for different business objects. The base class will handle opening a database connection that will be shared among all other instances for the lifetime of the request (a singleton, in other words). It'll look something like this:

```
public abstract class SqlRepository {
    protected SqlConnection dbconn;

    public SqlRepository() {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["dbconn"] == null) {
            dbconn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlRepositoryConnection"].ConnectionString);
            dbconn.Open();
            HttpContext.Current.Items["dbconn"] = dbconn;
        } else {
            dbconn = (SqlConnection)HttpContext.Current.Items["dbconn"];
        }
    }
}
```

The subclasses will implement various interfaces for different repository types, and will be injected via Ninject.

What, then, would be a good way to ensure that the database connection is closed at the end of each request lifecycle? I'd like to do it without a lot of extra dependencies, and without needing to explicitly close the connection from within controllers (because I'll have different build configurations for other dummy repositories, and might not even be using the SQL-based one while developing/debugging the front-end).

I suspect there's a simple solution, but I haven't done enough yet with MVC3 to know where I should handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do it in your controllers or in a controller base class, then do it in `Global.asax`.  Not the MVC way, but just 'cause you're using MVC doesn't mean everything has to be pure MVC.  These events still work fine:

```
private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conn = HttpContext.Current.Items["dbconn"];
    if (conn != null)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that. Is there any way to have the SqlRepository object register an event handler for Application_EndRequest, or will I need to put it all in Global.asax?

Comment: Ooh, that'll be perfect; thanks. I had a suspicion that I'd need to dig into HttpContext, but wasn't sure where to find what I was after.

Comment: "HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.EndRequest += Application_EndRquest" - DOES NOT WORK - EVENT IS NOT FIRED. The only thing works is method in Application class named exactly "Application_EndRquest"

Comment: @PhilippMunin, thanks for pointing that out.  It's not mentioned in the docs.  I removed that alternative.

Comment: I did some additional research, and figured out that, the only case when Application events subscription (like Application.EndRequest+=...) will work is when this subscribing code is being executed in/during Application.OnInit overload method.

Comment: @PhilippMunin, yup, they also changed the behavior in various versions of .NET.  In .NET 2 you could add the handlers and it would silently fail, in .NET 4 it throws an exception.  .NET 4 behavior is better.  Actual documentation would be best though.  :-) Thanks again for pointing it out.

Comment: I didn't see exception throwing - it just didn't fire event for me. I was testing it on .NET 4 .NET 4.5.

Comment: @PhilippMunin, interesting, the error I got is "System.InvalidOperationException: Event handlers can only be bound to HttpApplication events during IHttpModule initialization." on .NET 4.0.  It might depend on if you're using classic or integrated pipeline.  I tested using integrated.